# Long running function in .net core 6

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I've created an endpoint which takes in quite a bit of data and sometimes the processing of it takes from 5 to 20 minutes. I want to create an asynchronous HTTP API to handle this and similar future cases. I've been reading around and I can't come up with a solution that I would be happy with. We are hosting our application in an app service in Azure.

The solution that I think would be best for this use case leaning most towards to is to create a persistent azure function that would be created in the same as my main project. Here are the things I'm not sure about this solution and would love some clarifications:

1. The authn/authz is done through:

```
[Authorize] keyword  (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization)
```

and by registering authentication middleware:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer)
```

I would love to keep the same auth rules in my functions project, but I am assuming it cannot be done trivially.

2. The way those functions have to be called:

Is it sensible to have a controller method inside the main project to proxy the requests to azure functions? In that way, I could avoid thinking about auth and do that in the API project and have a symmetric key to call the functions.

Would love some thoughts and resources regarding this question. Please let me know if there's a better way to implement all of tihs.

Answer (score 1):

`[Authorize]` attribute is used to limit the access to the authenticated users in .NET Core Projects that can be applied to the controller.

In the same context, you have the [Authorization Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process,functionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#api-key-authorization) in Azure Functions also where you have the different levels such as `System`, `Admin`, `Anonymous`, `Function` and `User.`

[image]

Whatever the Authorization level setting is enabled, there is no impact on Azure Functions Project running locally and the same for the .NET Core Project Controllers also if the attribute `[AllowAnonymous]` comes with the Combination of `[Authorize]` attributes on the same controller level.

> No need to register the middleware the way we do for ASP.NET Core applications.

With the help of [Dark Loop](https://github.com/dark-loop/functions-authorize) NuGet Package`DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize`, you can apply authorize keyword/attribute to the Azure Functions also.
Here I have taken .NET 6 Azure Functions - Http Trigger Project with the above package installed and below is the code snippet for declaration of Authorize attribute on the Function Level:

```
using DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionAuthorize]
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(         [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel., "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
```

Refer to the MS Doc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration) & [2](https://github.com/mattchenderson/azure-functions-proxies-intro/blob/master/README.md) for the JWT Bearer Token Authentication Scheme Service to the Azure Functions .NET Example Code and handling the requests in Azure Functions Proxies.